# How to deal with Avenger and Overload Pulse

Tags: star-wars-armada

In my last game of Star Wars Armada, I flew an ISD II as [Avenger](http://starwars-armada.wikia.com/wiki/Avenger) and an Interdictor equipped with [Overload Pulse](http://starwars-armada.wikia.com/wiki/Overload_Pulse) and [Disposable Capacitors](http://starwars-armada.wikia.com/wiki/Disposable_Capacitors).
My commander was [Darth Vader](http://starwars-armada.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader), ensuring the OP trigger and an unfriendly result for the ISD attack.

The effects on the rebel ships were... exciting (took one attack from both ships to blast the MC80 out of space). After deciding to not use this combination again for a long time (my rebel player refused to fight this combination again) I was wondering what one might do against this commbination, as it appears to me to be overpowered.

So what would be a strategy to fight this combination.